# Installed Redmine on Ubuntu; But i have no clue how to use it to create Users/Projects/Roles/Tracking etc

Tags: project-management, redmine

Im new to Redmine. I installed redmine(with mysql) on Ubuntu 10.04.
The following were the installation steps I did:

```
* $ sudo apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql subversion
* $ ln -s /usr/share/redmine/public /var/www/redmine
* In /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf, added a PassengerDefaultUser www-data directive.
* Configured the /var/www/redmine location in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default:
    <Directory /var/www/redmine>
       RailsBaseURI /redmine
       PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    </Directory>
* $ sudo a2enmod passenger
* I then restarted the apache2 server.
```

That's it.
Now I typed `http://localhost/redmine/` in my browser and accessed my `redmine` instance.
So from here on, how do I create different users with with different privileges, create different projects, also update the issues and other project management related stuff.....
I know this sounds silly, but I couldn't find anything to proceed....

Comment: I don know wat credentials to sign-into the redmine with :( :( :(

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I figured we could use a default 'admin' log-in. Now I can log into my redmine instance. But the Email delivery is not configured, and notifications are disabled. How do I
Configure the SMTP server in config/email.yml? I cant even find a email.yml file in 'config' folder.....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to copy config/email.yml.example to config/email.yml

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration

Comment: You can get a copy of email.yml.example here: https://github.com/edavis10/redmine/tree/master/config

default username and password: admin (for both)

Then you just gotta dig around... redmine is super easy to configure and get going with. redmine.org has a lot of documentation and how-to's.

Comment: Hi Floyd i have edited the email.yml file as mentioned. But when i try to send a test mail i get this error:                             An error occurred while sending mail (Connection refused - connect(2))

Comment: can you post the relevant section of your email.yml?

Answer (score 0):

The contents of my email.yml file are as below:
production:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
        ssl: true
        address: "mail.abc.com"
        port: 465
        domain: "xyz.abc.com"
        authentication: :login
        user_name: "ronnie@abc.com"
        password: "pass"

Answer (score 0):

First question: Click on "administration" in your redmine instance. From there you can go to Users to add users, or Roles and permissions to change the permissions of different users etc.

Second question: Try connecting manually to your mail server from the redmine server using the "mail" command in a terminal. Then you'll at least be able to figure out if the redmine server at all can connect to your mail server.

Answer (score 0):

I created a user, then updated the database to give that user administrive rights. I have sqlite3 for my database, I used the following commands in IRB:

```
db = SQLite3::Database.new 'db/redmine.db'
db.execute("update users set admin=1")
```